# 'subscript(_:)' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int (Swift 5)

Tags: swift, uitableview, character, subscript, custom-sections

I have only found one answer to this here. My problem is I am not using `Character`s except for that's what a `String` is - a collection of characters. I tried making this a `String` viz;

```
        let name = String(array[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])
```

but I get the same error **Cannot assign value of type 'Character' to type 'String?'**.

Here's my cell:

```
struct SectionStrings {
    let sections = ["Stuff", "More Stuff", "Best Stuff"]
}

struct ArrayStrings {
    let array = ["Little Stuff", "Bigger Stuff", "Biggest Stuff"]

}

struct DetailArrayStrings {
    let detailArray = ["Teeny Stuff", "Teentsie Weentsie Stuff", "Invisible Stuff"]

}
```

Here's my controller:

```
let sections = SectionStrings().sections
var array = ArrayStrings().array
let detailArray = DetailArrayStrings().detailArray

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SettingsCell

        let name = array[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] // errors here
        cell.textLabel?.text = name
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white

        let detailName = detailArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] // and here
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = detailName
        cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = .white
        cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.backgroundColor = .black

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: `array` is `[String]` so `array[indexPath.section]` is a `String`. Adding `[indexPath.row]` part would be like trying to do `"hello"[5]`. That is the cause of your error. You are trying to treat `array` as a two dimensional array but it is only one dimensional.

Comment: So how should I count them, the number of strings in the array?

Comment: @rmaddy I tried a range `[..<index]` but I get an additional error **Binary operator '..<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'IndexPath'** - which makes sense because indexPath is not an Int or a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the required `name` for `indexPath` using `row` only as below,

```
let name = array[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = name
cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white

let detailName = detailArray[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: my index is out of range. Operators not working either :(

Comment: Nevermind that did it. I had to return 1 section in my `numberOfSections` and return `sections.count` in my numberOfRows. Thanks!